# Setting up Spring-Data-Neo4j standalone application causes Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j

I have spent numerous hours of setting this up. I am trying to setup a JUnit to test a simple NodeEntity class and a Repository. I am also using Gradle (not Maven -- to be Gradle seems cleaner then the Maven pom.xml). Also, I am using the Java Configuration class.

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin:'java'
apply plugin:'idea'

project.ext {
    springVersion = "4.0.3.RELEASE"
    neo4jVersion = "2.0.1.RELEASE"
    springDataGraphVersion = "3.0.1.RELEASE"

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    version = '1.0'
}

configurations {
    runtime
    testCompile
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'

    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:${springVersion}"
    compile "org.neo4j:neo4j:${neo4jVersion}"
    // Provides Repository based Object <-> Graph Mapping
    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:${springDataGraphVersion}"
    compile "javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA"

    testCompile 'junit:junit-dep:4.11'
    testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:${springVersion}"
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    // Access to Neo4j testing facilities: TestGraphDatabaseFactory
    testCompile "org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:${neo4jVersion}:tests@jar"
    testRuntime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.5'
}

// Generate wrapper for Gradle
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

**Test Class**

```
  import domains.BaseClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import repos.BaseClassRepository;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={AppConfigTest.class})
public class TestBaseClass {

    @Autowired
    private BaseClassRepository baseClassRepository;

    @Autowired
    private GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

    @Transactional
    @Test
    public void shouldCreateNode () {

        BaseClass testClass = null;

        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            testClass = new BaseClass();
            testClass.setName("Archer");
            baseClassRepository.save(testClass);
            tx.success();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }


        BaseClass testClass1 = baseClassRepository.findByName("Archer");
        assertEquals(testClass1.getName(), "Archer");

        System.out.println(testClass.getName());
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'baseClassRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'neo4jTemplate' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'neo4jTemplate' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 62 more
```

Also, for some reason the `shouldCreateNode()` function runs twice for the test. Not sure why either. =(

**AppConfigTest Configuration**

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.test.TestGraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "domains")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "repos")
public class AppConfigTest extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public AppConfigTest () {
        setBasePackage("domains");
    }

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your `AppConfigTest` class?

Comment: Whoops...should have done that... one sec ... @tonga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got a working solution.

For my AppConfigTest class. I needed to extend it from `Neo4jConfiguration` for it to `@Autowire` the Neo4jTemplate. I thought this was only for the real application.

Secondly, after I fixed I was getting a error similar to [spring-data-neo4j#161](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/161) on github. That error points you to the Neo4j Blog's post: [Spring-Data-Neo4j Progress Update SDN 3](http://blog.neo4j.org/2014/03/spring-data-neo4j-progress-update-sdn-3.html) which I was missing the `setBasePackages()` function in my constructor (see updated code in question).

Third, seems @NodeEntity objects can't contain vars in the constructor either. So removed that from my test when creating my base class.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains about

```
No bean named 'neo4jTemplate' is defined
```

which is in your test class `TestBaseClass`. So in order to inject the dependency of this class, you need to add the `Neo4jTemplate` bean in the configuration class:

```
public class AppConfigTest {
    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
            return new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTemplate neo4jBean() {
          return new Neo4jTemplate(graphDatabaseService());
    }
}
```

Note that [`Neo4jTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.3.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/Neo4jTemplate.html) class in latest Spring version has the constructor argument dependency on `GraphDatabaseService` class. So you can do the above to do bean injection via constructor argument.

Comment: Just give it a try. I just noticed that the error message shows the missing bean def.

Comment: I get `'Neo4jTemplate()' has protected access to 'org.springframework.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate'` on the `Neo4jTemplate()` function.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: As noted in my `build.gradle`:

    `springVersion = "4.0.3.RELEASE"`;
    `neo4jVersion = "2.0.1.RELEASE"`;
    `springDataGraphVersion = "3.0.1.RELEASE"`;

Comment: Well, that fix the error for the protected class. Testing it now.

Comment: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'neo4jTemplate' is defined`

Comment: hmm, sounds strange. The bean defined in `AppConfigTest` should be loaded in the application context in your test class. That's the only place I can see in the code that could cause bean not defined exception. You may also want to try removing `@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")`.

Comment: I already tried that. Which is what is making this so frustrating. Also, do you know why it runs the Test twice?

Comment: Also, after I got it working (look at my answer below) the double run tests went away. Strange.

Comment: Good to know. It seems strange that the AppConfig class needs to extend from `Neo4jConfiguration`.

Comment: Well, I have two AppConfigs. One for testing and one for the normal app. I knew the normal one did have to be but I couldn't find anything that told me the test one needed to be as well. Can be frustrating trying to find simple examples or answers to questions on line. Either A) the answer is "it works!" and no response to why or any details or 2) no good examples.